# Recover table and its data from SQL Server without backup and simple recovery model

Tags: sql-server

We have a case where we have deleted a table from the database, and now we do not have backup of that and the recovery model is set to simple.

We would like to know if it is possible to recover the table and its data. It's of high importance. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: No backup, and you want to recover the data - I'm afraid you're out of luck here..... learn to take backups!! Always. Period.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We do have backup but of older period. We just wanted to check if still it is possible to get the data back ???

Comment: If you don't have any recent backups, and you're running in "simple" recovery model, then you're pretty much out of luck, I'm afraid.... you cannot just "recover" a table and its data out of thin air......

Answer (score 0):

Check fn_dblog for possible solutions. There's a ton of help out on the web. (This might only work if the drop was within a transaction, unclear)

Here's a example:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3160/recover-deleted-sql-server-data-and-tables-with-the-help-of-transaction-log-and-lsns/

If that's not working there is a more expensive option with ApexSQL, who has a SQL recovery service that works without backups.

http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/rollback-drop-table-statement-without-backups/

Hope it helps

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.